# Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a .NET Core web application and I'm using VS Code as my IDE.  I built the app in .NET Core 2.2 but recently found out I need to downgrade to 2.0.

I changed the `<TargetFramework>` from 2.2 to 2.0.  Here is my `.csproj`:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
        <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App"/>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

When I try to run the project now I get this error:

> error NU1202: Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.0 is not compatible
> with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.0 supports: netcoreapp2.1
> (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1)

Do I need to change the version of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`?  Or maybe I need something completely different?

Comment: Possible to set target framework to 2.1? 2.0 is not LTS.

Comment: Unfortunately not.  Because I'm hosting with GoDaddy and they won't let me use anything above .NET 2.0    But it's not an issue anymore, I requested a refund and I'm moving my business elsewhere.

Comment: Please check [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/metapackage?view=aspnetcore-5.0), the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` metapackage apply to the ASP.NET Core 2.1 and later application. For the ASP.NET Core 2.0 application, try to use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` package.